# Match each character one time, including duplicates

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex that will take a set of characters (potentially including duplicates) and match on another set of characters.

For instance:

burritos would match to bcurritods, but wouldn't match to bcuritods, as it's short one 'r'.

Comment: A regex seems to be the wrong tool for this job.  Wouldn't it be easier to count the letter occurrences in each string and decide based on that?

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/oM7hH3/2

All you need to do is just search for the word you are looking for which in this case is burritos and then wrap it with the `\W*` to look for any non-word character before and after.

Edit: If you want to match just characters then you would have find the frequency of each letter. Check this answer for more information

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924457/6530840

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm specifically trying to match characters, not words. The order isn't going to always be the same.